# Error migrating user from SQL ASP.NET Identity DB (social account) to Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We currently have a an ASP.NET Identity SQL database that we are using to store our users for our application.  We are migrating those users to Azure AD B2C with social logins.  To migrate we are using the Azure AD Graph API to create the new users in Azure AD B2C.  Some users are created fine via the API, others fail with the following message:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en",
        "value": "Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Binary'. See the inner exception for more details."
    }
}
```

}

There's no reference to the inner exception that I can find in the response.  The body of the requests are nearly identical outside of the user guids.

Working:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "extension_db9f0616c9d6431596003b40cbd4933d_Bio": null,
    "createdDateTime": null,
    "creationType": null,
    "displayName": "SomeUserName",
    "givenName": null,
    "extension_db9f0616c9d6431596003b40cbd4933d_Institutions": null,
    "mailNickname": "69c16574-219b-4b88-84bc-426bbd9c19ed",
    "objectId": null,
    "extension_db9f0616c9d6431596003b40cbd4933d_SomeInternalIdString": null,
    "passwordPolicies": null,
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "NotNeeded1234!",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
    },
    "signInNames": [],
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": "69c16574-219b-4b88-84bc-426bbd9c19ed@<our_tenant>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "userIdentities": [{
        "issuer": "microsoft.com",
        "issuerUserId": "<SomeIdString>"
    }],
    "extension_db9f0616c9d6431596003b40cbd4933d_Websites": null
}
```

Failing:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "extension_db9f0616c9d6431596003b40cbd4933d_Bio": null,
    "createdDateTime": null,
    "creationType": null,
    "displayName": "SomeUserName",
    "givenName": null,
    "extension_db9f0616c9d6431596003b40cbd4933d_Institutions": null,
    "mailNickname": "c395b301-b19e-4f2e-adbc-29035045fb8a",
    "objectId": null,
    "extension_db9f0616c9d6431596003b40cbd4933d_SomeInternalIDString": null,
    "passwordPolicies": null,
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "NotNeeded1234!",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
    },
    "signInNames": [],
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": "c395b301-b19e-4f2e-adbc-29035045fb8a@<our_tenant>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "userIdentities": [{
        "issuer": "google.com",
        "issuerUserId": "<id_from_AspNetUserLoginsTable>"
    }],
    "extension_db9f0616c9d6431596003b40cbd4933d_Websites": null
}
```

Comment: Needed to Base64 Encode the IssuerUserId...gah.  MS need to update the documentation on this.

Comment: Agreed. It is mentioned in [this "Social identities migration introduction" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-social-migration#social-identities-migration-introduction). It would be better if it was also noted in [the "UserIdentity Type" documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#useridentity-type).